# Bitbucket when pushing to existing repo: fatal: unable to fork

Tags: git, bitbucket

I'm trying to connect my site to existing git repo, where i've added commits before from local project (not via ssh from server).
I'm kinda noob with git, but here's what i'm doing on server:

```
git remote add origin "my bitbucket ssh url here"
git add --all
git commit -m "production"
git push -f origin master
```

And after this i'm getting this error

```
fatal: unable to fork
```

What am I doing wrong? Fetching also gives such error. Adding upstream also doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server machine has no authorization to talk to your bitbucket repo. This is an ssh URL, so your server machine needs to do what you did on your local machine: create an ssh public-private key pair, and then hand the public key to bitbucket.

Answer (score 0):

Update your repo list and install openssh-server

```
$apt-get update
$apt-get install openssh-server
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).